# value of $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0+}\left ( \lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\left ( \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}+e^{nx}} \right ) \right )$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

What's the value of

$$
    \lim _{x\rightarrow 0+}\left ( \lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }\left ( \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}+e^{nx}} \right ) \right )
$$
?

I tried to consider about n first so I guess it equals to 0, however then it seems that x has nothing to do with the value. I don't know if I am correct  but could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: since $e^{nx}\to\infty$ for $n\to\infty$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}+e^{nx}}=0
$$
This doesn't depend on $x$. So when you compute the limit for $x\to0^+$, you get $0$ as well.